# TS/JS/Node - Transparent Observation of Abstract Class

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, observer-pattern

I have a base abstract class that I want public properties to be able to be Observed, including mutations if that property is an object/array/etc. This base class could take on a multitude of interfaces and other properties. I do not want someone who is using this base class to have to worry about events, a pub sub, or any other means of notification; I want that all just baked in.

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    #stores: Map<any, Function[]>

    subscribe(prop: NonFunctionPropertyNames<this>, callback: (data: CallbackType)=>void){
        // handle subscribe
    }

    unsubscribe(prop: NonFunctionPropertyNames<this>, callback: (data: CallbackType)=>void){
       // handle unsubscribe
    }

    constructor(){
        this.#stores = new Map<any, Function[]>
    }
}
```

I have attempted this using both `Proxy` and `get/set` each with their own pros and cons.

**Proxy**

- Pros

  - Can intercept anything that happens on the proxied class including mutations
- Cons

  - Does not copy private fields and any methods that reference a private field will error out the program

**Get/Set**

- Pros

  - Does not need to clone methods and can therefore play nice with private fields
- Cons

  - Only works on assignment and does not intercept any mutations that might happen on a property

I can live with the Get/Set approach, but that does mean anyone using this base class must be sure to re-assign a prop after any mutations. Is there some other approach I am missing?

**Clarity Edit**

The actual implemented classes are "2nd" party. I may or may not be the one to implement the actual class, but they are still part of the same "framework". This is for a "framework" to handle different IoT style devices.

The idea was/is to provide base functionality (BaseClass) and additional common interfaces for framing the implemented classes. This way the specific details of a particular IoT device were only specific to that particular class. Goal is to de-couple the nitty gritty details of a particular IoT device from functionally using said IoT device at the application level.

Comment: For plain objects and arrays that are stored in properties, you can use a proxy. For everything else, require it to be a `BaseClass` subclass instance, and observe it.

Comment: "*I may or may not be the one to implement the actual class, but they are still part of the same "framework".*" - in that case you're the first party and the implementer is the second party. (Or the other way round, depending on the perspective.) No third party around. I'd just drop the term from the title.

Comment: Updated to hopefully reflect more clearly

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be able to bolt on functionality.

## Are you sure?

I think your best bet is to reconsider what you're trying to do. Instead of a generic way to bend third-party classes to your will, maybe what you should be doing is using an adapter pattern to wrap third party classes in a way that, if you ever want to switch 3rd party libraries, you only need to change your adapter class because everything in your app uses it.

However, if your needs require it...

## Don't try inheritance

The way to do what you seek shouldn't be a master class, especially if you are talking about 3rd party classes because you won't be able to easily modify them to include your `BaseClass` as an ancestor!

## Utility function

Your best bet is to use a utility function that takes an object and the property you want to watch and...

1. has a `let` variable within that utility function so that it's "private" from everything outside of the utility function,
2. has an initially empty array of subscribers in another variable
3. adds a method for subscribing (i.e. adding a function to the array of subscribers)
4. Adds/replaces a setter that either sets the `let` variable above or, if there's already a setter, calls the original setter, then (asynchronously?) calls each subscriber.
5. Adds a getter as well as appropriate.

And that way you now have a property that can be subscribed to.

Once you have this, you can iterate through an object's properties and call the above function for each.

However, there are gotchas.

## Are the inputs mutated?

Let's say something gives your third party classes an object or array, and then changes it. If the third party code stores objects or arrays it is given, this is a problem unless it deep clones it's inputs before storage.

## Does the 3rd party class mutate it's own properties?

At first you might not have an answer for this.

Then you might think "Well, what if I just deep-mutate all objects and arrays *within* the properties I want to watch? That way if anything changes, I'll know!"

But consider a getter that actually returns a global, or session-stored value that could be changed by anything else!

There is no way to protect yourself on this one.

## Does the 3rd party class expose it's mutable properties?

If you can change the properties of an instance of a third-party class by getting a property (via property or a method) and changing it, so can other things.

## Immutable.js

So at this point, maybe you would be able to change or wrap a class instance so that getters return immutable output and setters clone their inputs and make them immutable, but then you have to be prepared for how that will likely infect others' classes with your bugs.

## Are you really, really sure?

I've spent a lot of time mulling your question over, and my final advice is this: Stop. Save your sanity and stop. Now.

Comment: "*a generic way to bend third-party classes to your will*" - I don't see any indication of attempting that in the OPs question

Comment: I hope you're right.

Comment: I think my initial goal was maybe a bit ambiguous. I am trying to provide common class functionality within a framework. The actual classes are "pseudo" 3rd party in that I may not be the one to implement a particular class, but they are still part of the same "framework" Read update and see if that makes any more sense.